# How can I get the latest changes in a file using ifstream?

Tags: c++

It's a real-time capture system, I need to get the latest changes from a file which is occasionally edited(mostly add content)  by other applications.
In other words, how can I get content that added in the period when I open it without reopening the file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ifstream tfile("temp.txt",ios::in);
    if(!tfile){
            cout<<"open failed"<<endl;
            return 0;
    }
    string str;
    while(1){
            if(tfile.eof())
                continue;
            getline(tfile,str);
            cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    tfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the [C++17 `<filesystem>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)? The function [`last_write_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time) sounds like what you need.

Comment: thx, I will check it out

Comment: I believe this is out of scope of the C++ iostream library (ifstream) and also the filesystem library. It has more to do with opening the file using operating-system specific apis or settings.  E.g., in Windows, you need to open the file using FILE_SHARE_WRITE and then continually query GetFileInformation for the current end of file - then read appropriately.  (AFAIK, but I'm very willing to be corrected.)

Comment: Yes, I think so. Actually it's in Linux. I'm thinking if I should set  a system cron task.

Comment: Or set a new task to keep watch on changes of the target file.

Comment: If you're talking about polling for changes via cron or some async task, then your problem is easier as you're willing to close and reopen the file.  If you want to keep the file open and just read new data: That's where I don't know how far you can get with iostreams.  You can reset eof I think and try again to read ... just don't know if that works properly with iostream's buffering.  Also you probably must be in binary mode, not text mode, for that.

Comment: it's originally about mysql binary logs. And I completely agree that the key of this problem is in buffers.

Comment: if it is linux you should use inotify

Comment: thx for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## C++ / C Solution

If you are looking for a c++ solution you can use the following functions that I had created a while back:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


// For sleep function
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

using namespace std;


void watchLogs(const char *FILENAME) {
    FILE * f;
    unsigned size = 0;
    f = fopen(FILENAME , "r");
    char c;

    while (true) {
        if (!size) { // will print content of your log file. If you just want the updates you can remove the current content except the first two lines;
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
            size =(unsigned long)ftell(f) ;
            fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
            char buffer[size + 1];
            fread ( buffer, 1, size, f );
            buffer[size] = '\0';
            cout << buffer << "\n";
        }
        else if ((c = (char)fgetc(f)) >= 0) {
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); // reach end of file
            int  BUFFER_SIZE =(unsigned long)ftell(f) - size; // save the length of the update to your logs
            char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1]; // prepare a buffer to print the characters
            fseek(f,-BUFFER_SIZE,SEEK_END); // rewind BUFFER_SIZE characters before the EOF
            int i = 0;
            do {buffer[i++] = (char)fgetc(f);} while(i < BUFFER_SIZE); // copy to buffer
            buffer[i] = '\0'; // don't forget to NULL terminate your buffer
            cout << buffer << "\n";
            size += i; // increment the size of the current file
        }
    }
    sleep(3); // updates are checked every 3 seconds to avoid running the cpu at fullspeed, you could set the new logs to show up every minutes or every seconds, up to you.
    fclose(f);
}
```

And you can test it with:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char  **argv) {
    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;
    const char *FILENAME = argv[1];

    watchLogs(FILENAME);

    return 0;
}
```

`./a.out mysql_binary.log`

I could have used stringstreamer but I like that this version would also work with c files with some minor tweaks (can't use string).
**I hope you will find it helpful!**

NB: This assume that your file will only grow and that the changes will be appended to the end of your file.

NB2: This program is not segfault proof, you may want to check the return of fopen etc

---

## Inotify

If you use Linux you could also potentially go for inotify:

Download inotify: `sudo apt-get install -y inotify-tools`

Then create the following script mywatch.sh

```
while inotifywait -e close_write $1; do ./$1; done
```

Give permission to execute:

```
add chmox +x mywatch.sh
```

and call it with `./watchit.sh mysql_binary.log`